# Angular 6 why index.html removed from URL

Tags: angular, sharepoint-2013

I have an angular application deployed to SharePoint but when page load "index.aspx" has been removed from the URL, so when user refresh it's given him different page URL and doesn't have permission for that URL

Answer (score 1):

For this fix change a little angular.json

```
{
  "projects": {
    "yourApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "index": "src/index.html", // place where you put path
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```